# Android how to not cancel previous alarm while setting new one

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm

Ok, as it is in [AlarmManager.set](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)):

> If there is already an alarm scheduled for the same IntentSender, that previous alarm will first be canceled.

How can I change this default behaviour?
I need to shedule alarms only once.
And if new alarms will be sheduled (with the same `PengingIntent`), I need to ignore them.

So I need the new alarm to be cancelled, but previous to be valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got it.

I created `PendingIntent` with no `FLAG` option.
Then I have method:

```
private boolean isPresent() {
    return PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null;
}
```

When I'm tryin' to set new `Alarm` - first I check - is this `PendingIntent` present.
And, when `Alarm` fires - I cancel `myPendingIntent` manually by calling `cancel()`.

This works good, as I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a proper way to do this.

A workaround would be to know if pending intent was already schedule by AlarmManager before sending.

Store a timestamp describing date of intent with [SharedPreference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html). Check if the timestamp was passed before sending another PendingIntent to AlarmManager.

Comment: Yeap, seems it's the only way to do it. But I'll try to find a better solution, if it's exist.